# Apache Camel - Kafka producer: setting topic name dynamically

Tags: spring, apache-camel, apache-kafka

I have a camel-base application (spring with routes described in XML). I'd like it to be able to route the input messages to an unknown number of kafka topics (based on a configurable matching between filename patterns and topic names) so i cannot create a producer per pattern in advance in the xml file.

Ideally we would be to be able to set the topic in the message header, like the partition id...

Does anyone has a suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it is possible. I was refering to the wrong sources of the kafka consumer. In the most recent releases, it behaves exactly as I hoped it would.

```
topic = exchange.getIn().getHeader(KafkaConstants.TOPIC, topic, String.class);
```

So one has to set the KafkaCOnstants.TOPIC header in the message in order to dynamically chose the topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can set topic using KafkaConstants.TOPIC in headers and read the value in kafka component something like kafka:${headers[kafka.TOPIC]}(this is in java dsl) to retrieve the topic and use toD uri to construct the kafka uri dynamically.